# loading two different table data into one flat file then got this error

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

Hi I have one doubt in ssis,

while loading two different table data into one flat file then got this error.
how to avoid this error
[Flat File Destination [2]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "C:\Users\Desktop\emp.txt".
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Flat File Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.

source server1: emp
source1 server 2: emp
destination flatfile: emptxt file

in sequent container I took two dft task

one dft for one server  configur emp source table and mapping to the destination emptxt file
second dft for 2nd server and configur emp source table and mapping to the destination same emptxt file

whie I running this two dft parallel exectuion that time I got this error
[Flat File Destination [2]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "C:\Users\Desktop\emp.txt".
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Flat File Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.

in my process two dft should be process parallel only.(if run sequence order  its working fine)
in controal flow we can use two diferenct oledb source and combine the data and mapping to destination table.

is it possible or not  for run parallel of two dft task with same flat file using ssis package

how to avoid this error to achive this task in ssis

Answer (score 0):

Please check this option works out. Instead of 2 DFT, take 2 data sources in 1  DFT .Use union all and load the destination file.

Regards,
Achu